# in javascript how can I detect if a browser will display or download a pdf?

Tags: javascript

Say I have:

- a webpage with an iframe: `<iframe src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>`
- an URL pointing to a PDF document: `http://www.example.com`
- some javascript that will do `iframe.src = pdfurl`
- a button that will trigger such javascript
- if the browser is going to display the PDF inline, the button will
  say "view pdf" and when clicked will make the iframe visible
- otherwise it will say "download pdf"

I found a way to detect whether the pdf has been loaded in the iframe: reading `iframe.contentDocument.contentType` after `onload` has fired, but

- this won't allow me to display the correct button
- `onload` does not fire if the file is being downloaded

Thanks :)

Comment: Users don't understand the difference between viewing a file in the browser and downloading it anyway. IMO "View PDF" is fine in both cases, because it will open in their PDF viewer or browser plugin. If they don't even have a viewer, the browser/shell will display a "system can't display PDF" message, making them understand they need some additional software, which you could supply with one of these nice "Get Adobe PDF" links (though I'd prefer Foxit Reader). So I would not really bother to get this right, because you never know which plugin exactly the user uses and whether it is enabled.

Comment: sounds like an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 5):

To tell the client's browser to download a response as a file, set the Content-Disposition HTTP header to 'attachment' in your response. This is no guarantee, but it's the proper method of telling the browser how to handle the content.

Answer (score 3):

> #### [§ 8.9.1.6 PDF viewing support](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#pdf-viewing-support)
>
> ##### `window.navigator.pdfViewerEnabled`
>
> Returns `true` if the user agent supports inline viewing of PDF files when
> navigating to them, or `false` otherwise. In the latter case, PDF files
> will be handled by external software.

[MDN web docs article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled).

#### Browser compatibility table

[image: Support table]

Answer (score 1):

In modern Browsers, JavaScripts global Navigator object has a plugins property, filled with an array of Plugins, if you can find a Plugin for Mimetype application/pdf, you can safely assume that the browser will display pdf files inline, as long as the server does not explicit send content-disposition: attachment headers, of course.

Comment: This seems to be true for webkit based browsers only. For Firefox, you need to load a pdf and see if PDFViewerApplication is loaded or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could send a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) to that resource and check what `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` values are being sent back. Based on these information you could determine whether a browser would display or download that resource.

Comment: Only if you assume that the browser will have a PDF displaying plugin installed and configured to be used by default. It find such things so irritating that I make a point of uninstalling or blocking them.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Content-Type and Content-Disposition
are sent from the server to the client. The server won't have any knowlwdge about browser capabilities. The server can exploit those two headers to force the browser to perform a download instead of a display.